# Fixing a dropped merge

Tags: git

I have a scenario in which certain changes have been dropped when 2 parallel feature branches are merged into its parent branch. Something like this,

```
     C1-D1-E1
    /        \
A--B          F*-G
    \        /
     C2-D2-E2
```

F* - Merge conflict resolved

The changes for the branch is being done in the above way, and I've lost all the changes that are done in the branch `C2-D2-E2` due to the wrong resolution. The reason why the changes are lost but still the log contains the commit id is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43928592/2046462).

To fix it, when I try to merge back the branch containing those files, it won't as the commits from the branch are already part of the log.  What is the best way of bringing back the lost changes to the main branch?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way of bringing back the lost changes ...

What's the **best** way to eat an egg?  Start from the big end, or from the little end? ([ref](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Spring_2003/ling538/Lecnotes/ADfn1.htm))

Or, to put it another way, there isn't a *best* way.  There are just ways that work, or don't work.  These ways may be easier, or harder, or may be better for some particular situation you have, or not.

Two relatively simple options are:

- cherry-pick the range of commits using `git cherry-pick`, or
- Pick from the merge using `git revert -m` (but this one is a little tricky to explain).

#### Cherry-picking

Cherry-picking is, in essence, the process of *copying* a commit.  In essence, we have Git compare a commit to its parent commit.  That is, suppose we have a series of commits like this:

```
...--o--o   <-- master
      \
       o--o--P--C--o--o   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

At commit `P` (the parent), while working on branch `feature`, we discover some nasty bug and fix it in child commit `C`.  We'd like to make an immediate fix to `master`.  We could `git checkout master; git merge <hash-of-C>` to merge in `C` but that would bring along three more commits: the two before `P`, then `P` itself.  So we run `git checkout master`, giving us:

```
...--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       o--o--P--C--o--o   <-- feature
```

Now we run `git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>`.  Git compares the snapshot in commit `P` to the snapshot in commit `C` to see how we fixed the bug, then makes *the same changes* to our current index and work-tree, and commits the result with a copy of the commit message from `C` too, giving us:

```
...--o--o--C'  <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       o--o--P--C--o--o   <-- feature
```

We have, in effect, *copied* commit `C` to new commit `C'`.  It has the same *message* as `C`, and does the same *thing to the code* as `C` did to `P`, but it's a different commit, at a different place in the graph.

#### Using this to correct your merge

You have:

```
     C1-D1-E1
    /        \
A--B          F--G   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
    \        /
     C2-D2-E2
```

where `F` is a faulty merge (perhaps done with `git merge -s ours`) that drops some or all of the work from `C2-D2-E2`.  Cherry-picking those three commits will make three new commits, each of which does what those three commits did.

To cherry-pick `C2`, `D2`, and `E2` with one simple command, assuming that `F^2` is `E2` (i.e., that `E2` is the *second* parent of `F`), you could run:

```
git cherry-pick F^2~3..F^2
```

(replace `F` with the appropriate hash ID, or use `HEAD^` to name it through commit `G`, e.g., `git cherry-pick HEAD^^2~3..HEAD^^2`).

#### Cherry-pick vs revert

Sometimes, we'd like not so much to *copy* a commit, as to *undo* it.  That is, suppose we have:

```
...--o--P--C--o--o   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Looking through history, we realize that commit `C` is just a mistake.  If we could just *undo* it, we'd be fine.  This is where `git revert` comes in.  We tell Git to `git revert <hash-of-C>` and Git compares `P` and `C` to see what changed, then *un-does* that change.  The result is a new commit that is the opposite of `C` (I'll draw it as `3` which is not as good as Ↄ but Ↄ may not be in all fonts and it renders oddly in computer-text in my browswer):

```
...--o--P--C--o--o--3   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Technically, both cherry-pick and revert use Git's *merge engine*.  They set the merge base commit to `P` for cherry-pick and the two inputs are `HEAD` and `C`; or, for revert, the merge base is `C` and the two inputs are `HEAD` and `P`.  Git then does a full three-way merge, and if all goes well, commits the result as an ordinary commit, with the `HEAD` commit as the new commit's parent.  But you only need this technical note if you must resolve merge conflicts—the *effect* of a cherry-pick or revert is to re-apply, or un-do, changes found by comparing a commit to its parent.

#### Cherry-picking or reverting a merge

A *merge commit* is one with at least two parents (and most have only two parents).  Since cherry-picking works by comparing the commit with its parent, there's no obvious way to cherry-pick a merge.  It has *two* parents and Git can't compare with both simultaneously.<sup>1</sup>  But this also means there is no obvious way to *revert* a merge, and Git needs a way to revert a merge.  So both `git cherry-pick` and `git revert` allow for an option, `-m`.  When you give this option, you also give a *parent number*.  Git then pretends, for the duration of the cherry-pick or merge command, that the merge commit has just *one* parent: the one you selected.

This means that if we run:

```
git revert -m 2 <hash-of-F>
```

where `F` is your bad merge, Git will compare the snapshot in `F` to the snapshot in `E2`, to see what changed.  If you manually run that same diff, using `F` as the first commit and `E2` as the second:

```
git diff F F^2
```

you'll see the changes that Git will attempt to apply.

If you do run this `git revert`, you'll probably want to add `--edit` so that you can edit the commit message if Git is able to apply these changes on its own.  That's because the default message for a revert is particularly poor for this case: Git will just claim that the new commit reverts commit `F`, when in fact, what you are doing is recovering code that was lost along the way.